# How to hide the "+2" in my achievements dialog button when I accept an answer?

Tags: feature-request, reputation, accepted-answer, achievements-dialog, userscript

I already know that when I accept an answer, my reputation will gain 2 points. Because it isn't much, I don't feel that I need to give it a care. If it can be disappeared for an amount of time, I don't have any trouble for showing it. However, it stays there until I click it so I feel irritating. The same for "+100" when I assign to a new site.

Is there any way to not showing it? Via a userscript, perhaps?

<sup>Related: [How to hide the welcome back message effectively?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/316361/260800)</sup>

Comment: `Do not show me “+2” in my achievements dialog`. Do not see the +2 in your achievements in your dialog ;)

Comment: @CheckBox that's funny :))

Comment: Why not? It's the same rep. No different from +5, +10, +100 or +1000. No reason to hide it whatsoever.

Comment: @ShadowWizard ok, I has changed my question.

Comment: Fair enough, so the answer is simple: "you can't". (maybe some userscript, if you have the time and skills :))

Answer (score 2):

I think this is quite useful, in particular for new users that aren't very familiar with the way the SE sites work. Showing the +2 for accepting makes new users see their 'benefit' in accepting an answer.

For regular, more established, users I indeed see it isn't that necessary. To be honest, I don't particularly care if it shows or not. (Although consistency is important, so I say: let's keep it!)

Comment: I understand. Is there a way to get rid of it?

Comment: Yes, Please ignore it !

Comment: I think the option provided by Check Box is the best ;)

Comment: @CheckBox I... just... can't :(

Comment: Also, I would like to get rid the "+100" when I assign to a new site

Comment: I'd say Give it a try