# How to hide the welcome back message effectively?

Tags: discussion, notification-bar, userscript

In theory, using the [`*` wildcard](https://github.com/gorhill/uBlock/wiki/Static-filter-syntax#-aka-all-urls) on uBlock Origin should work, but it doesn't:

```
*.stackexchange.com###overlay-header
```

How to do this properly?

[image]

<sup>Related: [Disable “don't forget to vote” message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/89045/260800) in Meta Stack Exchange</sup>

Comment: Ublock origin: I have experimented with `stackexchange.com###overlay-header` instead. It does work wonderfully. It only fails for some sites of the network without that pattern, so manually add them to the "my filters" in the like of `superuser.com###overlay-header`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The userscript [Stack Overflow Extras (SOX)](https://stackapps.com/q/6091/29559) supports hiding this banner.

[image]

<sup>Report issues: [Remove the welcome back message · Issue #315 · soscripted/sox](https://github.com/soscripted/sox/issues/315#issuecomment-392529667)</sup>

Answer (score 10):

Here is a filter list for Adblock and uBlock.

1. Open your ad-blocker extension advanced settings
2. Click on "Change filters"
3. Copy-paste the contents of [this gist](https://gist.github.com/sguillia/083f5cd5582e412a0a74c9279e818bcf) inside the filters list

For uBlock, add the contents into the third tab *My list*, or just import the link to *Filters list* (the second tab)

[image]

I don't know why the wildcard doesn't work.

The gist is merely a list of all stack exchange URLs with `###overlay-header` appended to each line.

The list was retrieved [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/240392/341222) and arranged with this command line:

```
sed -n -e 's/^.*http//p' < input | cut -d'/' -f3 | sed -n -e 's/[[:blank:]]*$//p' | sed -n -e 's/$/###overlay-header/p' | sort > output
```

I see this message sometimes 10 times a day because I browse on different SE communities.